# dynamically change a part of the variable path

Tags: variables, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times, but none of the answers (or at least what i took away from them) was a help to my particiular problem.

I want to dynamically change a part of the variable path, so i don't have to repeat the same code x-times with just two characters changing.

Here's what i got:

In the beginning of my script, i'm setting the reference to PlayerData scripts, attached to the GameManager object like this:

```
var P1 : P1_Data;
var P2 : P2_Data;

function Start(){
    P1 = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent.<P1_Data>();
    P2 = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent.<P2_Data>();
}
```

Later, i want to access these scripts using the currentPlayer variable to dynamically adjust the path:

```
 var currentPlayer : String = "P1"; //this actually happens along with some other stuff in the SwitchPlayers function, i just put it here for better understanding

 if (currentPlayer.PlayerEnergy >= value){
 // do stuff
 }
```

As i was afraid, i got an error saying, that PlayerEnergy was not a part of UnityEngine.String.

So how do I get unity to read "currentPlayer" as part of the variable path?
 
Maybe some parse function I haven't found?
 
Or am I going down an entirely wrong road here?

Cheers

PS: I also tried putting the P1 and P2 variables into an array and access them like this: 
     `if (PlayerData[CurrentPlayerInt].PlayerEnergy >= value){
     // do stuff
     }`
to no success.

Comment: Is there really no way to do this? Or is the answer so basic, that i should have figured it out by myself? (I have not) I highly doubt that people write endless if cases, for a function with just one variable changeing in each case...

Comment: One way i figured, was to directly bind the path to the _currentPlayer_ var like `if (currentplayerCount == 1){currentPlayer = GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent.<P1_Data>();}` for each player. But I get an error, when I don't set a type for _currentPlayer_. What type of variable do I declare currentPlayer to be here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no reply providing the answer I needed, I'll share the solution that did the trick for me, provided by a fellow student.

Instead of having the PlayerData scripts pre-written, I generate them using a `public class` function in a Playermanager script. This generates the Playerdata as attached scripts, saved into an array. 
I can then access them through `Playermanager.Playerlist[Playernumber].targetvariable`.
Which is what I wanted to do, only with the Playerdata being attached to a script instead of a gameobject. And it works great!

Here's the full code of my Playermanager Script:

```
//initialise max players
public var maxplayers : int = 2;

// Initialise Playerlist
static var Players = new List.<PlayerData>();


function Start () {
 for (var i : int = 0; i < maxplayers; i++){ 
     var Player = new PlayerData();
     Players.Add(Player);
     Players[i].PlayerName = "Player " + i; 
 }  

 DontDestroyOnLoad (transform.gameObject);   
 }

public class PlayerData {

  public var PlayerName : String;
  public var PlayerEnergy : int = 15; 
  public var Fleet : List.<GameObject> = new List.<GameObject>(); 

}
```

As you see, you can put any type of variable in this class.
I hope this helps some of you who have the same problem.

cheers, 
Tux

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

> var currentPlayer : String = "P1"

here P1 is just string, not the previous P1/P2 which are referenced to two scripts. So, if you want, you can change

> currentPlayer.PlayerEnergy >= value

to

> P1.PlayerEnergy >= value

or,

> P2.PlayerEnergy >= value

But if you just want one function for them, like

> currentPlayer.PlayerEnergy >= value

Then you have to first set currentPlayer to P1/P2 which I assume you are trying to do. You must have some codes that can verify which player is selected. Then, maybe this can help -

```
var playerSelected: int = 0;
var currentPlayerEnergy: int = 0;

.....

//Use your codes to verify which player is selected and then,

if (playerSelected == 1) {
    currentPlayerEnergy = P1.PlayerEnergy;
} else if (playerSelected == 2) {
    currentPlayerEnergy = P2.PlayerEnergy;
}

//Now use your favorite function
if (currentPlayerEnergy >= value) {
//Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately (while it might do the trick for others) it is not the solution I'm looking for. Since I'm adressing a lot of the variables in PlayerData script, for different players in the exact same way, it would really be the best solution if i could just swap P1 with P2 in the variable-path. 
I could of course hard code it with `if (currentPlayer == x){//do stuff for x}` for all players, but that would feel kind of wrong somehow... there's gotta be a better way to do this. Also, I wonder how there's not more people asking this. Am I overlooking something trivial here?